# Filling column if information is available in another row

Tags: r, data.table

I have data as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(ZIP_source1 = c(1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 
1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1017, 1012, 1012), ZIP_source2 = c(1026, 
1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1012, 1012), 
    Category_source2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
dat

    ZIP_source1 ZIP_source2 Category_source2
 1:        1016        1016        4
 2:        1016        1016        4
 3:        1016        1016        4
 4:        1016        1016        4
 5:        1016        1016        4
 6:        1016        1016        4
 7:        1016          NA       NA
 8:        1016          NA       NA
 9:        1016          NA       NA
10:        1016          NA       NA
11:        1027          NA       NA
12:        1022        1022        4
13:        1022        1022        4
```

For line 7 to 10, I know from source 1 what the zip code is. From source 2 I know that this zip code
falls in category 4. What is the best way to do this?

Desired output:

```
    ZIP_source1 ZIP_source2 Category_source2
 1:        1016        1016        4
 2:        1016        1016        4
 3:        1016        1016        4
 4:        1016        1016        4
 5:        1016        1016        4
 6:        1016        1016        4
 7:        1016          NA        4
 8:        1016          NA        4
 9:        1016          NA        4
10:        1016          NA        4
11:        1027          NA       NA
12:        1022        1022        4
13:        1022        1022        4
```

Comment: How do you know zip code 1027 is in category 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
   group_by(ZIP_source1) %>% 
   fill(Category_source2, .direction = "downup")
```

---

Or using `nafill`

```
library(data.table)
dat[, Category_source2 := nafill(nafill(Category_source2, 
    type = "locf"), type = "nocb"), ZIP_source1]
```

-output

```
> dat
    ZIP_source1 ZIP_source2 Category_source2
          <num>       <num>            <num>
 1:        1026        1026                4
 2:        1026        1026                4
 3:        1026        1026                4
 4:        1026        1026                4
 5:        1026        1026                4
 6:        1026        1026                4
 7:        1026          NA                4
 8:        1026          NA                4
 9:        1026          NA                4
10:        1026          NA                4
11:        1017          NA               NA
12:        1012        1012                4
13:        1012        1012                4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I noticed that I made the example slightly too simplistic, because I need to fill several columns (also a character column). I thought of changing your code to `dat[, (cols):= nafill(nafill(cols, 
    type = "locf"), type = "nocb"), ZIP_source1]`, with `cols <- c("Category_source2", "Zip_source2")`. But that does not work. Could you perhaps tell me the syntax for multiple columns?

Comment: @Tom WIth the first code, you just need `fill(all_of(cols), .direction = "downup")` and in the second, you may need `dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) nafill(nafill(x, type = "locf"), type = "nocb"), by = ZIP_source1, .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: ^ Missing parenthesis after `type = "nocb` in comment by akrun: `dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) nafill(nafill(x, type = "locf"), type = "nocb")), by = ZIP_source1, .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: @Tom sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to create new columns to do this, which I will call `zip` and `category`, but it's straightforward to overwrite the original columns if you want.

```r
# Get all zips where not NA in one column
dat  <- dat  %>% 
    mutate(
        zip = coalesce(ZIP_source1, ZIP_source2)
    )

# Create table of all categories
category_table  <- dat  %>% 
    select(Category_source2, zip)  %>% 
    drop_na()  %>% 
    group_by(zip)  %>% 
    distinct()  %>% 
    rename(category = Category_source2)

category_table
#   category   zip   
#      <dbl> <dbl>   
# 1        4  1026   
# 2        4  1012   

# Join as new column
left_join(dat, category_table, by = "zip")

#     left_join(dat, category_table, by = "zip")
#    ZIP_source1 ZIP_source2 Category_source2  zip category
# 1         1026        1026                4 1026        4
# 2         1026        1026                4 1026        4
# 3         1026        1026                4 1026        4
# 4         1026        1026                4 1026        4
# 5         1026        1026                4 1026        4
# 6         1026        1026                4 1026        4
# 7         1026          NA               NA 1026        4
# 8         1026          NA               NA 1026        4
# 9         1026          NA               NA 1026        4
# 10        1026          NA               NA 1026        4
# 11        1017          NA               NA 1017       NA
# 12        1012        1012                4 1012        4
# 13        1012        1012                4 1012        4
```