# Fill both numerical and character columns, conditional on the previous and next value being equal

Tags: r, interpolation, na

Please note that my question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648980/r-fill-down-multiple-columns):

In the following data, I would like to fill both numerical and character columns which are `NA`, based on the conditions that `areacode` and `type` of the zipcode before the `NA` is the same `areacode` and `type` of the zipcode after the `NA`.

In words: *"Because zipcode 1002 had clay and zipcode 1004 has clay, we assume that zipcode 1003 has clay."*

I wanted to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859870/filling-column-if-information-is-available-in-another-row), but `na.fill` only fills numerical values.

```
dat <- structure(list(zipcode = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004), areacode = c(4, 
4, NA, 4), type = structure(c(3L, 3L, NA, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"sand", "clay", "na2"), class = "factor"), region = c(3, 3, 
NA, 3)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

   zipcode areacode type region
1:    1001        4 clay      3
2:    1002        4 clay      3
3:    1003       NA <NA>     NA
4:    1004        4 clay      3

dat2 <- structure(list(zipcode = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004), areacode = c(4, 
4, NA, 1), type = structure(c(3L, 3L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"sand", "clay", "na2"), class = "factor"), region = c(3, 3, NA, 
3)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

   zipcode areacode type region
1:    1001        4 clay      3
2:    1002        4 clay      3
3:    1003       NA <NA>     NA
4:    1004        1 sand      3
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Desired output `dat`:

```
   zipcode areacode type region
1:    1001        4 clay      3
2:    1002        4 clay      3
3:    1003        4 clay      3
4:    1004        4 clay      3
```

Desired output `dat2`:

```
   zipcode areacode type region
1:    1001        4 clay      3
2:    1002        4 clay      3
3:    1003       NA <NA>     NA
4:    1004        1 sand      3
```

## EDIT:

The following would not be enough, because it would fill in `clay` even if the fourth row says `sand`.

```
dat2 %>%
  fill(areacode, type, region)

   zipcode areacode type region
1:    1001        4 clay      3
2:    1002        4 clay      3
3:    1003        4 clay      3
4:    1004        1 sand      3

dat2[, lapply(.SD, zoo::na.locf)]

   zipcode areacode type region
1:    1001        4 clay      3
2:    1002        4 clay      3
3:    1003        4 clay      3
4:    1004        1 sand      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 |> 
  mutate(type = as.character(type)) |> 
  mutate(across(2:4,
                ~ ifelse(is.na(.) & lag(areacode) == lead(areacode) & lag(type) == lead(type),
                         lag(.),
                         .)))

  zipcode areacode type region
1    1001        4 clay      3
2    1002        4 clay      3
3    1003       NA <NA>     NA
4    1004        1 sand      3

dat |> 
  mutate(type = as.character(type)) |> 
  mutate(across(2:4,
                ~ ifelse(is.na(.) & lag(areacode) == lead(areacode) & lag(type) == lead(type),
                         lag(.),
                         .)))

  zipcode areacode type region
1    1001        4 clay      3
2    1002        4 clay      3
3    1003        4 clay      3
4    1004        4 clay      3
```